# Which acceleration is being talked about when one says "An accelerated charge loses continuously, in the form of EM radiation"?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, reference-frames, maxwell-equations

> An accelerated charge loses energy continuously, in the form of EM radiation.

Which acceleration is being talked about here? (note that it is a frame dependent quantity)

It should not be possible for the charge to lose energy in one frame and not in the other. Could anyone please solve this conceptual doubt?

Comment: Maxwell's laws only hold true in inertial frames.

Comment: The acceleration with respect to any inertial frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula):
$$P=\frac{q^2a^2}{6\pi\varepsilon_0c^3}$$
for a particle of charge $q$ and acceleration $a$ traveling at non-relativistic speeds. However, we can generalize this via special relativity, and show that the power emitted is indeed frame-independent. Take a frame which is instantaneously at rest with the particle - essentially nearly inertial. In this frame, $d\mathbf{p}=0$ for the spacelike components of the four-momentum $\mathbf{p}$. However, the timelike component does not vanish, and transforms to another inertial frame as
$$dE'=\gamma dE$$
where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor. Additionally, the time interval also varies as
$$dt'=\gamma dt$$
and so
$$P'=\frac{dE'}{dt'}=\frac{\gamma}{\gamma}\frac{dE}{dt}=P$$